# I am trying to integrate chef and rundeck

Tags: chef-infra, rundeck

I am trying to integrate chef and rundeck. I installed rundeck on chef workstation and trying to run command on local server only. Normal commands are working fine like "uname -a" but when I am writing cmd like "service httpd status" (httpd is already installed on workstation) I am getting error. Can anyone help me? (I am new to rundeck please use layman language).Thanks.

Comment: Which error do you get? Do you need `sudo`?

Comment: It was giving error saying rundeck needs root permission to run this job. So I tried "sudo service httpd status" but error was the same. I don't know how to give root permission to rundeck .

Comment: If you can help on finding useful docs on chef and rundeck integration , it will be very helpful to me.
Error:...
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Result: 1
Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 1
Execution failed: 8 in project s: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [localhost: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 1]}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for your following questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without ever having used rundeck, a quick search reveals the [Secondary Sudo Password Authentication](http://rundeck.org/docs/plugins-user-guide/ssh-plugins.html#secondary-sudo-password-authentication) section in the documentation.

When you follow [Sudo Password as a Job Option](http://rundeck.org/docs/plugins-user-guide/ssh-plugins.html#sudo-password-as-a-job-option), you are guided as follows and will probably asked for the sudo password when running the job:

> Configure a Job, and include an Option definition where secureInput is set to true. The name of this option can be anything you want, but the default value of sudoPassword recognized by the plugin can be used.
>
> An example Node and Job option configuration are below:
>
> ```xml
> <node name="egon" description="egon" osFamily="unix"
>     username="rundeck"
>     hostname="egon"
>     sudo-command-enabled="true"
>     sudo-password-option="option.sudoPassword2" />
> ```
>
> Job:
>
> ```xml
> <joblist>
>     <job>
>          <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
>           <command>
>             <exec>sudo apachectl restart</exec>
>           </command>
>         </sequence>
>
>         <context>
>           <project>project</project>
>           <options>
>             <option required='true' name='sudoPassword2' secure='true' 
>                     description="Sudo authentication password"/>
>           </options>
>         </context>
>         ...
>     </job>
> </joblist>
> ```

Comment: It was helpful answer. Still I have some doubts. Do I need to create rundeck user in each nodes and give it root permission? Can you please explain how the trust will be created between rundeck server and nodes?

Comment: No, I never used Rundeck. There should be information about that available in the Internet. Search for it, please. Once you have specific questions, ask again.